# How can I make a height dynamic in iOS with WebView, Nativescript?

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

The problem I have is that the WebView does not load height dynamically in iOS (in Android if it does), the question is that my content is dynamic and can grow high, and putting the fixed height would not work for me. Could you help me?

```
<CardView *ngFor="let itinerario of itinerario" class="card" elevation="40" radius="10" ios:shadowRadius="3">
   <StackLayout class="card-layout text-center">
      <WebView [src]="itinerario.mEstructura" height="auto"></WebView>
   </StackLayout>
</CardView>
```

Comment: `itinerario.mEstructura` - Is it local webpage from your assets or a remote one? One easier solution is (if you have control over the webpage), write a JS function to calculate the height and update it in the location hash which you can read from app. If you don't have control on the webpage, then you may have to write some native code to get the height once the webpage is loaded.

Comment: I don't have control over the page, that's the problem where they make it dynamic and add X content. How could I do it with native code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use native method to evaluate JavaScript that can return height of the document.

**HTML**

```
<GridLayout>
    <ScrollView class="page">
        <StackLayout>
            <WebView src="https://www.nativescript.org/" [height]="height"
                (loadFinished)="onWebViewLoadFinished($event)"></WebView>
            <Button class="btn btn-primary" text="Hello!"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</GridLayout>
```

**TS**

```
 onWebViewLoadFinished(event: EventData) {
    const webView = <WebView>event.object,
        jsStr = `var body = document.body;
        var html = document.documentElement;
        Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);`;

    if (webView.ios) {
        webView.ios.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
        webView.ios.evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler(jsStr,
            (
                result,
                error
            ) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error...");
                } else if (result) {
                    this.height = layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(result);
                    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                }
            });
    } else if (webView.android) {
        // Works only on Android 19 and above
        webView.android.evaluateJavascript(
            jsStr,
            new android.webkit.ValueCallback({
                onReceiveValue: (height) => {
                    this.height = layout.toDeviceIndependentPixels(height);
                    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
                }
            })
        );
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=1v0jG9)

Answer (score 3):

I adapted @manoj's answer for nativescript-vue.

```
<template>
   <ScrollView>
     <StackLayout>
       <WebView
         src="https://www.nativescript.org/"
         @loadFinished="loadFinished"
         :ios:height="iosHeight"
       />
     </StackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    loadFinished(args) {
      if (!global.isIOS) {
        return;
      }
      const webview = args.object;
      const jsStr = `let body = document.body;
        let html = document.documentElement;
        Math.max(body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight,
          html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);`;
      webview.ios.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false;
      webview.ios.evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler(
        jsStr,
        (result, error) => {
          if (result) {
            this.iosHeight = result;
          }
        }
      );
    },
  },
};
</script>
```